# How secure is using public computer?

Tags: tls, public-key-infrastructure

I got questioned about the security of using public computers and sending data with them. I am using HTTPS which is based on SSL, while SSL uses PKI which is hard to hack. Thus, there is nothing to worry about while using a public computer. Is it right? (I don't take into account cases with computer-based viruses like Trojan)

Comment: The whole problem with public computers is that they may have (legitimate or outright malicious) spyware installed. Not taking that into consideration is unreasonable to say the least. Also, a public computer may have certificate installed in the root of trust, which would allow MITM and inspection of even your HTTPS protected traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Not Secure At All

HTTPS mitigates against several threats, such as:

- An attacker impersonating the server you try to communicate with
- An attacker reading your communication between you and the server
- An attacker modifying your communication between you and the server

However, these are all **network-based attacks**. On a public computer, the attacker has many ways of compromising you, (and even compromise guarantees made by HTTPS). For example, an attacker could

- Install a Keylogger and wait for you to log into an account of yours
- Install a custom Certificate Authority, allowing them to impersonate any server (e.g. Facebook, Google, etc.)
- Install a screen recording software to spy on your private data while you view it

There are many other ways how an attacker can gain access to your data, should you choose to enter or read sensitive data on a compromised machine.

Comment: Dont forget browser hooking.

Answer (score 1):

> How secure is using public computer?

**From the [Microsoft immutable laws of security](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/archive/blogs/rhalbheer/ten-immutable-laws-of-security-version-2-0):**

> If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it’s
> not your computer anymore

which means everything you see or send can be tampered with and faked on a system that you do not own.